# Check if an HTML file is online or local folder

Tags: javascript

i'm loocking for a javascript code (if it's possible) to check if an HTML file has been launched/read from a remote host or from a local folder of pc.

..let me explain better with an example:

i've an html file in **C:/folder/file.html** 
if i launch it by double-clicking, a js script print *"read from local"* on the document.

Now, if i host it on a my website, like **www.mydomain.org/file.html**
and open that page, the js script print *"read from online"*

This would be greatly helpful,
thank you for now.

Comment: You could check `window.location.protocol`. Typically it's `file:` when a page is loaded from a local folder.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[window.location.protocol](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/protocol)

can give you whether the file is local ("file:") or website ("http:")

Which is implemented by [window.location](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location)